# Formating number in flutter dart datacell (data From API)

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, formatting, numbers

I Hope anyone can help..
How to format number with thousand separator whil this's data get form API.
My Code is like this:

```
Future<List<Data>> fetchData() async {
        var url = Uri.parse('https://bps-3301-asap.my.id/api/sensus-tani-rtup');
       final response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var cokk = jsonDecode(response.body);
          return (cokk['data'] as List).map((data) => Data.fromJson(data)).toList();
      } else {
          throw Exception('Unexpected error occured!');
      }
    }
```

I wanto display data from that API with separate thousand (with ".").
this the code in data table:

```
    DataCell(
                      Text(
                       data.rtup.toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                         color: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 17, 17),
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                         fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

I want to display rtup and other data cell get from API as number with thousand sepatator. Try many way but still fail.
very appreciated for any one can help. Txh U

Output right now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd4Va.png)

Ouput what i want is all the number display with ("." for thusand) like
11.171
18.197

I use formatter with package intl before (and it's work), but now i m working with datable while datacell get data from API.

PS: Sorry for my english

Comment: Please share the data output

Comment: Please share expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "intl" package for this.
Just add intl to your project and import it. Then you can use it like this

```
  String thousandCommaSeperator(String amount){
    var formatter = NumberFormat('#,###,000');
    if(amount.isNotEmpty) {
      return formatter.format(double.tryParse(amount));
    }
    else{
      return 'N/A';
    }
  }
```

For this example I have used intl: ^0.17.0.
And I have created a method for changing number. Just call this method in your view.

Comment: Thx alot for your answer. i've try it. But can not figure out how to place that code in data cell and how to call in my vie. I m a not to good in dart programing. Can you more spesific where i should put that code and where and how to call in my view?

Comment: Thx man! Finally it's work i've already make a function Format.converTo  Just add double.tryparse and it's done... Thx again.

(Format.convertTo(
                                    double.tryParse(data.pangan_rtup), 0)),

Comment: Welcome Ahmed . Glad to know that it helped. Don't forget to accept the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thx man! Finally it's work i've already make a function

```dart
class Format {
  static String convertTo(dynamic number, int decimalDigit) {
    NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.currency(
      locale: 'id',
      symbol: '',
      decimalDigits: decimalDigit,
    );
    return currencyFormatter.format(number);
  }
}
```

i m just add double.tryParse

(Format.convertTo( double.tryParse(data.pangan_rtup), 0)), –

Thx again.